# How to open file with ofstream so that other users can append/write to same file?

Tags: c++, linux, file

We have a binary which creates a daily `CSV report` with some file name like Sample_20170523 i.e filename appended with current date but now the issue is when some other runs the binary on the same day then there is error unable to open the file.Code snippet for this issue is as follows:

```
std::ofstream of;
of.open("FileName_20170523",ios::out);
if(!of)
  std::cout<<"Unable to open file..."<<std::endl;
```

So after checking it seems this problem arises because the file was already created by another user. So just wanted to know is there any mechanism in c++ in which we can give 777 permissions to programmatically created file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `chmod()` or `fchmod()` to change the permission of a file.

Comment: `fchmod` requires a file descriptor. AFAIK there's no standard way to get the FD from an `fstream`.

Comment: Both these approaches seems to be very crude and non-c++ way of doing things

Comment: @Kapil Well, if you have C++ 17 you can use the filesystem function `std::filesystem::permissions()`, before that you can use `boost::filesystem`. But before that, you're bound to the good old C functions.

Comment: @Barmar Right. In this context, `chmod()` would be the function to use.

Comment: You may find that your compiler/library has `<experimental/filesystem>` support, if not 'official' filesystem library support. It is worth a look, certainly.

Answer (score 0):

system() allows to execute system commands.

```
system("chmod 777 diretory_to_file/name");
```

gives r+w+x to everyone if it already exits

```
std::ofstream of;
of.open("FileName_20170523",ios::out);
```